# Upload Photo Rotation Issue

Tags: magento2.4, image-upload

I have an issue with Magento 2.4.4 upload Photo. as you can see after uploading a picture there is a rotation of the image.
I did a quick search and found that this problem comes when a photo is uploaded with iPhone and EXIF data. I already tried following the code in uploader.php. but, did not work. please check the code and SS. does anyone got the same issue?

```
 if ((strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) && exif_imagetype($this->_file['tmp_name']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->_file['tmp_name']);
                $rotate = imagerotate($source, 270, 0);
                imagejpeg($rotate, $this->_file['tmp_name']);
            }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

IN this file vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php

this code use :

```
if ((strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) && exif_imagetype($this->_file['tmp_name']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->_file['tmp_name']);
            $rotate = imagerotate($source, 270, 0);
            imagejpeg($rotate, $this->_file['tmp_name']);
        }
```

Before This Line

```
$this->_result = $this->_moveFile($this->_file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile);
```

Comment: I already placed that code. Can you confirm that is correct in following way? https://ibb.co/zS4kKX6

Comment: yes, it is currect

Comment: okay if not works can be a cache issue? i have to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ?

Comment: yes check it it is working ?

Comment: Ping you asap :) Can you confirm i have to run setup:static-content:deploy ?